# Proper structure of array for the test POST request

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, parsing

im making a new post page in which I`ll be sending data to API.

The POST body parameter is this:

```
{
    "user": "some user",
    "hashTag": "some hashtag",
    "description": "some text",
    "images": [{
        "postImageURL": "some url",
        "tag": [{
            "tagId": "some id",
            "name": "some name",
            "xPosition": "",
            "yPosition": ""
        }]
    }]
}
```

Right now Im sending this array:

```
 func postTap() {
        let parameters: [String:Any] = ["user": "some user",
                                        "hashTag": "somehashtag",
                                        "description": "some text",
                                        "images": []]

// Some code... JSONSerialization and etc...
}
```

How do I add images, postImageUrl, tag and other properties to the parameter array?

And it would be great if you could share the essential source for learning json structures (nested/flat) and how to parse them correctly. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the easiest way to do this is to create an Encodable struct, and populate it with the values you want. You can serialise this to JSON in one go:

```swift
struct Tag: Encodable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let xPosition: String
    let yPosition: String
}

struct Image: Encodable {
    let postImageURL: String
    let tags: [Tag]
}

struct PostItem: Encodable {
    let user: String
    let hashTag: String
    let description: String
    let images: [Image]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it important for PostItem struct to be the last in order? And one more question. 
`guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: [PostItem], options: []) else { return }`

`request.httpBody = httpBody`
Is this how I should serialise it in one go? Thanks

Comment: @Russ in a Playground, yes, in an Xcode project, no, the order doesn't matter. I wouldn't try to serialise in one go if you have to ask the question. A few extra lines of code for readability never hurt anyone.